# Как в Vuex передать данные типа this.$route.params.id?

Tags: vue.js

Есть такой запрос к REST API.

```
queryParams['brend_id'] = this.$route.params.subid;

                callApi('prod_cat', queryParams, '').then((res) => {
                    if (res.data.data.length) {
                        this.categories = res.data.data;
                        for (var i = 0, max = this.categories.length; i < max; i++ ) {
                            if (this.categories[i].id == this.$route.params.id) {
                                this.currentCategory = this.categories[i]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
```

callApi - функция, делающая запрос к REST API

prod_cat - URL‐путь

queryParams - это параметры после URL‐пути.

Только начала знакомиться с VUEX и мне нужно теперь все данные получать с его помощью. 
Есть запросы без this.$route.params.subid, с ними более-менее понятно как работать. А вот как делать запросы, где нужно знать параметры текущей страницы сайта совсем не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно поставить соответствующий плагин для того, чтобы было проще работать с связкой vuex + vue-router: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync

Далее, просто передаете с помощью `argument destruction` `rootState` в `action` в котором у вас вызывается запрос.

```
someAction({commit, rootState}) {
    let routeParams = rootState.route.params;
}
```